# Oracle Scheduler Job Executor, or who is the USER during Job Runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a function in a package which returns special value, when the USER = SYS.
I have a Job scheduled in Scheduler to be executed daily. For strange reasons I am getting errors on some DB instances, indicating, that the USER is not really SYS, but <SCHEMA>.
I am using Oracle SQL Database 11g version.

From my tests I have found just one way how to have different USER in a Job. It is when the Job is scheduled directly by user USER=<SCHEMA>. Problem is, that this is an unlikely scenario, because normally all the scripts are executed under SYS.

Please, could you explain me how the determination of Job "executor" really works? Is there a way of determining by PL/SQL script who the Job executor will be? Can you direct me to a documentation, which would describe it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG / DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1139.htm#i1587038

2) Do you REALLY need SYS account to execute the job ? In most production systems this causes a lot of DBAs concerns, they hardly allow user-defined jobs executing under SYS.

One more useful link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schedover.htm#i1106753

"
You can create a job in another schema by specifying schema.job_name. The creator of a job is, therefore, not necessarily the job owner. The job owner is the user in whose schema the job is created, while the job creator is the user who is creating the job. Jobs are executed with the privileges of the schema in which the job is created. The NLS environment of the job when it runs is that which was present at the time the job was created.

After a job is created, it can be queried using the *_SCHEDULER_JOBS views. Jobs are created disabled by default and need to be enabled to run.
"

Comment: Thank you very much for such fast response! If I get it correctly now, then when I have a Job1 created by USER=SYS under SCHEMA1, the executor is SYS. When Job2 is created by USER=SCHEMA1 under SCHEMA1, the executor is SCHEMA1(When the Job2 JOB_ACTION='DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Logged in user: ' || USER);' it would return SCHEMA1)
Problem is, I do not have a chance to query the USER. Since for OPERATION=RUN is ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG.USER_NAME=null. For OPERATION<>RUN is USER_NAME no longer null, but these values are long gone, cause of automatic log disposal.

Comment: Just found ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS which has JOB_CREATOR